# Fedex Web Services: ERROR 9040 - Can't pull up tracking

Tags: php, soap, fedex

I'm having issues attempting to pull up tracking info using Fedex's Web Services. I am using a valid tracking number and I'm able to view the details on Fedex's site. However, I get an error 9040 "No information for the following shipments has been received by our system yet.  Please try again or contact Customer Service at 1.800.Go.FedEx(R) 800.463.3339." Am I leaving something out?

My code:

```
<?php

$path_to_wsdl = "URL_TO_WSDL";
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'UserCredential' =>array(
        'Key' => 'MY_KEY', 
        'Password' => 'MY_PASSWORD'
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => 'MY_ACCT', 
    'MeterNumber' => 'MY_METER'
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => 'ActiveShipping');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'trck', 
    'Major' => '5', 
    'Intermediate' => '0', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['PackageIdentifier'] = array(
    'Value' => 'TRACKING#',
    'Type' => 'TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG');

$response = $client->track($request);
var_dump($response);


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

Call the web services departement and they told me to remove 'beta' from the wsdl file. This appears to be a different address than what I found in responses to this problem before. On line 1507 of the wsdl file, make the following change:

From:

```
<s1:address location="https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/track"/>
```

To

```
<s1:address location="https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/track"/>
```

I changed the rest of my code slightly, but that shouldn't have made the difference. To be on the safe side, here it is:

```
<?php
$path_to_wsdl = "PATH_TO_WSDL_FILE";

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

$trackRequest = array(
    'WebAuthenticationDetail' => array(
        'UserCredential' => array(
            'Key'      => 'MY_KEY',
            'Password' => 'MY_PASSWORD'
        )
    ),
    'ClientDetail' => array(
        'AccountNumber' => 'MY_ACCT_#',
        'MeterNumber'   => 'MY_METER_#'
    ),
    'Version' => array(
        'ServiceId'    => 'trck',
        'Major'        => '5',
        'Intermediate' => '0',
        'Minor'        => '0'
    ),
    'PackageIdentifier' => array(
        'Type'  => 'TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG',
        'Value' => 'THE_TRACKING_#',
    ),
    'CustomerTrasactionId',
    'IncludeDetailedScans' => 1
);
$response = $client->track($trackRequest);
var_dump($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on this same problem. I'm trying several things and you can see if anything works for you. Try including ShipDateRangeBegin and End elements, your test account/payer numbers or destination info. I've found [here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-198288.html) that switching to xml and ssl post requests supposedly solve the problem, but it's not an option for me. Maybe it will help you?

Comment: Downgrading to version 4 of the wsdl doesn't help. I think that there's something wrong on the fedex end as far as processing incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when use xml-request. I solved the problem this way:

```
$endpointurl = "https://gatewaybeta.fedex.com:443/xml"; // remove word "beta"
$endpointurl = "https://gateway.fedex.com:443/xml";

...
$request = stream_context_create($form);
$browser = fopen($endpointurl , 'rb' , false , $request);
$response = stream_get_contents($browser);
...
```