# FedEx tracking API error 9040 - Java Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, soap, fedex

I have an assignment that requires me to use FedEx's tracking API using Java to communicate with their server.  I downloaded all the client code from their developer website.  I added my credentials to the source code and attempted to test the code using some tracking numbers I have.

When testing the numbers on the tracking website I get the confirmation that things have been delivered to their locations.  But when I try using the same values with the supplied client code I get this error message:

```
    Message: No information for the following shipments has been
      received by our system yet.  Please try again or contact Customer
      Service at 1.800.Go.FedEx(R) 800.463.3339.
```

After googleing the issue I found this solution (A stackoverflow thread):

[Fedex Web Services: ERROR 9040 - Can't pull up tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924294/fedex-web-services-error-9040-cant-pull-up-tracking)

I tried this solution by changing the PortType locaiton from
        https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/track 
to 
        https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/track

But all that happens now is that I get no response at all.  Here are links to the source code that I am working with (I would paste it but its close to 600 lines)

Client code: http://pastebin.com/9xwraHYP

Service PortType Provider: http://pastebin.com/ZVkqsAuv

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I get no response at all"_ -- How do you know? Have you followed the network traffic with Wireshark?

Comment: @Jim Garrison No, at lines 72-75 i would have the code uncommented which will display FAIL if the call was successful.  I never used Wireshark I'll look it up now.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know is that FedEx **does** **not** provide any test tracking numbers, so you should change the endpoint to production ([How track by Tracking Number Unique Identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065390/how-track-by-tracking-number-unique-identifier/18084885#18084885)).

The second step is to obtain a real FedEx tracking number, and perform a tracking request.

Best!

Answer (score 0):

FedEx provide testing tracking id

Test Tracking Id: 123456789012

You can also use: 111111111111