# FedEx web Integration ERROR CODE 9004

Tags: php, soap, fedex

I am trying to integrate the tracking services of FedEx on to my webapp and I keep getting this error..

> Severity: FAILURE
>  Source: prxy
>  Code: 9004
>  Message:
>   Remote EJB method: track not called. Unable to create the remote bean.
>   Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: unable to find primary
>   representative [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unable
>   to find primary representative]. Cause: javax.naming.NamingException:
>   unable to find primary representative [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NamingException: unable to find primary representative]

Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-      ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v10"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:TrackRequest> <ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail><ns1:ParentCredential><ns1:Key>#########</ns1:Key><ns1:Password>###########</ns1:Password></ns1:ParentCredential><ns1:UserCredential><ns1:Key>#############</ns1:Key><ns1:Password>###########</ns1:Password></ns1:UserCredential></ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail><ns1:ClientDetail><ns1:AccountNumber>#########</ns1:AccountNumber><ns1:MeterNumber>###########</ns1:MeterNumber></ns1:ClientDetail><ns1:TransactionDetail><ns1:CustomerTransactionId>*** Track  using PHP ***</ns1:CustomerTransactionId></ns1:TransactionDetail><ns1:Version><ns1:ServiceId>trck</ns1:ServiceId><ns1:Major>10</ns1:Major><ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate><ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor></ns1:Version><ns1:SelectionDetails><ns1:PackageIdentifier> <ns1:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</ns1:Type><ns1:Value>449044304137821</ns1:Value></ns1:PackageIdentifier><ns1:ShipmentAccountNumber>########</ns1:ShipmentAccountNumber> </ns1:SelectionDetails></ns1:TrackRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><TrackReply xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v10"><HighestSeverity>FAILURE</HighestSeverity><Notifications><Severity>FAILURE</Severity><Source>prxy</Source><Code>9004</Code><Message>Remote EJB method: track not called. Unable to create the remote bean. Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: unable to find primary representative [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unable to find primary representative]. Cause: javax.naming.NamingException: unable to find primary representative [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unable to find primary representative]</Message></Notifications></TrackReply></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using the Laravel framework and there are three files used for this Fedex integration, i.e., TrackService_v10.wsdl which contains the XML data, TrackWebServiceClient.php5 which contains the php functions to send a request and the fedex-common.php5 which also contains the php functions containing the input to post.

I have tried looking everywhere on the internet and the Developer and resource center on FedEx but I really cant get it working. I also dont understand this SOAP requests. Also, FedEx says they dont have programmers to help me with this. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having the exact same issue. After banging my head on the desk for hours, I came across this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941234/5632365. It pertains to v5 of the WSDL file (current is 10), but basically you need to remove "beta" from the URL on line 2296.

```
<service name="TrackService">
    <port name="TrackServicePort" binding="ns:TrackServiceSoapBinding">
      <s1:address location="https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/track"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Should be

```
<service name="TrackService">
    <port name="TrackServicePort" binding="ns:TrackServiceSoapBinding">
      <s1:address location="https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/track"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

And magically everything will (should) start to work. Hope this helps you as much as it did me!

Comment: Yes!! Ît works :) .. Thanks a lot. Been trying for 36 hours to get this thing working. Finally!! Thank you

Comment: Note, as for now, keeping the wsbeta should work. I've issue now when I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `beta` doesn't seem to be the good solution anymore.

I've been in contact with Fedex support and the issue actually comes when you set invalid "ParentCredentials".

In my case I only have to use "UserCredential", "ParentCredentials" was set to "XXX" if empty in the (Java) example provided by Fedex.